# Use YaST through a SOCKS5 proxy

Tags: ssh, proxy

I am ssh'ing into a server (SLES 10 sp2) that does not have access to the internet.
I need to run updates and install new software on this server, preferably using Yast.

So my idea was:

1. Create a proxy using ssh to a box that has access to the outside.
2. Setup Yast to use this proxy.

The ssh command I run on the isolated server looks as follows:

```
ssh -D 9999 username@ip-of-box-with-internet-access
```

In Yast I go to *Network Service > Proxy* and enter the following as the HTTP Proxy URL:

```
http://localhost:9999
```

When I go to *Test proxy settings* it fails.

I suspect that Yast does not know it is a SOCKS5 proxy.

Could anyone tell me how I can setup Yast to use a proxy created with ssh?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An "HTTP Proxy" and a "SOCKS5 Proxy" aren't the same thing.  That's why YAST doesn't get it :)

A quick fix would be to install Squid or some other HTTP proxy on `ip-of-box-with-internet-access` , and then do something like `ssh -L 12345:localhost:8080 user@ip-of-box-with-internet-access` from the server.  I do this all the time.

An example of a quick HTTP proxy would be [micro proxy](http://www.acme.com/software/micro_proxy/), but I haven't used that and thus can't give a recommendation.  Squid isn't too bad to set up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This would explain why my attempted solution did not work. Could you quickly explanation the differences between the two proxies? Thanks!

Comment: They speak a different protocol, is all.  HTTP proxies are made to do HTTP(S) connections only. SOCKS5 is for arbitrary IP connections.  Most HTTP proxies allow you to do a direct connection (CONNECT foo.com:443), but that's somewhat of a hack.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS#Comparison_between_SOCKS_and_HTTP_proxies for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you have a machine on the network that does *not* have it's traffic routed through a gateway to the internet, but it is on a network with other machines that DO have their traffic routed through a gateway to the internet.

1.) Why is the box isolated? Is it a security risk or is it paranoia? Firewall rules should be sufficient to keep the box isolated from the network while still allowing outbound connections and respondents to those connections.

2.) The easier way may be to use a VPN software as opposed to a proxy. YAST uses a variety of protocols and subtools (i.e. curl) to fetch patches, most of which ignore other systemwide settings.

3.) Instead of a proxy, you may consider using a VPN solution or setting up a local mirror using Novell's patch mirroring application ([called 'SMT'](http://download.novell.com/Download?buildid=5YxjWD8_ZZk)) and your mirror credentials (both available from the Novell customer center.)

Comment: Thanks for your help. The box is isolated because we're using the infrastructure supplied by our office park and they haven't patched through our external ip-address yet. I'll have a look at VPNs to see if I can use it as a quick temp solution. Thanks again!